# Missing where attribute in the options parameter - sequelize

Tags: node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize version 4.8.0. This looks like it should be correct according to the docs http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update, however, I'm getting this error: `Missing where attribute in the options parameter`

```
const role = req.body;

sequelize.transaction((t)=> {
    return sequelize.models.role.update(role, {where: req.params, transaction:t}).then(() => {
        res.json({success: true});          
    })
  })
  .catch(errorCatch(res));
}
```

logging `req.params` shows that it is this: `{ id: 'f212d399-f139-4d76-b892-7c2a83281f9b' }` so that's not where the problem is. 
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong. I think it may have something to do with the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I made this endpoint as a GraphQL mutation and it work with basically the same code. I also changed my sequelize to 3.30.2, but I don't that had anything to do with it working in the mutation because I tried that with the endpoint as well.

```
const UpdateRole = {
 type: ResponsePayload,
 args: baseUpdate,
 resolve: (root, role, context) => {
  return joiValidate({
    permission: "WriteRole",
    obj: role,
    joiModel: roleJoiModel,
    user: context.user
  }).then(() => {
  return sequelize.transaction(t => {
    return sequelize.models.role
      .update(role, { where: { id: role.id } }, { transaction: t })
      .then(() => {
        return sequelize.models.role.findOne({ where: { id: role.id } });
      })
      .then(r => {
        return Promise.all([
          r.setPermissions(role.permissions || [], { transaction: t }),
          r.setUsers(role.users || [], { transaction: t })
        ]);
      })
      .then(r => {
        if (role.isDefault) {
          return sequelize.models.role
            .update(
              { isDefault: false },
              {
                where: {
                  id: {
                    $ne: role.id
                  }
                }
              }
            )
            .then(() => {
              return Promise.resolve({ success: true });
            });
        } else {
          return Promise.resolve({ success: true });
        }
      });
     });
    });
```